# Field "to" must be a JSON string [Firebase]

Tags: php, android, json, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send notification using a cron job. I migrated from GCM to FCM. In my server side, I changed `https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send to https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send` and also updated on how to request the data changing `registration_ids` to `to`. Checking the json passed it is a valid json but I'm having an error `Field "to" must be a JSON string`. Is there anyway to solve this?

Here is my code

```
function sendNotificationFCM($apiKey, $registrationIDs, $messageText,$id) {


    $headers = array(
            'Content-Type:application/json',
            'Authorization:key=' . $apiKey
    );

    $message = array(
            'to' => $registrationIDs,
            'data' => array(
                    "message" => $messageText,
                    "id" => $id,
            ),
    );


    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($message)
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<strike>Try explicitly converting `$registrationIDs` to `string`.</strike>

```
$message = array(
        'to' => (string)$registrationIDs,
        'data' => array(
                "message" => $messageText,
                "id" => $id,
        ),
);
```

**Edited Answer**

The `'to'` parameter requires a `string` - which is the recipient of the message.

The `$registrationIDs` could be passed a separate parameter (as string array) to `'registration_ids'`

Edit your code to something like this:

```
$recipient = "YOUR_MESSAGE_RECIPIENT";

$message = array(
        'to' => $recipient,
        'registration_ids' => $registrationIDs,
        'data' => array(
                "message" => $messageText,
                "id" => $id,
        ),
);
```

Where `$recipient` is

> a registration token, notification key, or topic.

Refer this: 
[Firebase Cloud Messaging HTTP Protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json)

Comment: will `(string)` convert the `$registrationIDs` like "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvD, 1234asd:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvD, bk3RNwTe3H0:asds_HwgIpoDKCIZvvD" this?

Comment: No, it wont. I guess your `$registrationIDs` is a string array. The `'to'` key requires a string, and I assumed that  `$registrationIDs` must have been int, which it isnt, hence I suggested to cast it to string.

Comment: my `$registrationIDs` have the registration tokens

Comment: @mori then `'to'` is optional, see the link in the answer

Comment: should I  only use `registration_ids` ? but when i use that my device doesn't receive any notification.

Comment: @mori Yes, you should use `registration_ids` for sending a multicast message when you have multiple recipients. If your application is not working as intended it is unrelated to the question. Check the response code in your server code and also check for any errors in your client app(android). Post a different question regarding your problem if you cannot solve it. For now you could accept the answer if it solved your error posted in this question.

Comment: Must use either "registration_ids" field or "to", not both

Answer (score 2):

Try making to as a string:

```
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

{
  "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
  "data" : {
   ...
 },
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// if you are using an array like
$fcm_ids = array();
$fcm_ids[] = "id_1";
$fcm_ids[] = "id_2";
$fcm_ids[] = "id_3";
//.
//.
//.
$fcm_ids[] = "id_n";
// note: limit is 1000 to send notifications to multiple ids at once.
// in your messsage send notification function use ids like this
$json_data = [
"to" => implode($fcm_ids),
"notification" => [
    "title" => $title,
    "body" => $body,
    ],
"data" => [
    "str_1" => "something",
    "str_2" => "something",
    .
    .
    .
    "str_n" => "something"
    ]
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. It turns out when I retrieved the Registration Token from my Firebase database (using this [Firebase PHP Client](https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php)), it was returned with double quotes at the beginning and at the end of the token. So I had to remove the first and last characters from the token before I could use it. The code below solved my problem

```
substr($registrationToken, 1, -1)
```